# How to globally replace the "," with ";" in CSV file?

Tags: csv, powershell

For example, the following csv file.

```
123,"a,b,c",456
```

will become

```
123,"a;b;c",456
```

The following code generates an empty file (test.txt) and it's slow.

```
Import-Csv file.csv | % {
    $r = @{}
    foreach($v in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ($v.Value -like "*,*") {
            $r | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $v.Name -Value ($v.Value -replace ",",";")
        }
        else {
            $r | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $v.Name -Value ($v.Value)
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your code to something like this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\file.csv'

$properties = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.Name

$csv | % {
  foreach ($p in $properties) {
    $_.$p = $_.$p -replace ',', ';'
  }
  $_   # "passthru"
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\test.txt' -NoType
```

That evaluates the property names just once and also avoids creating new objects and adding new members to them all the time.

Comment: It takes 23 minutes to process a 3MB file.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 A test run of the above with an (admittedly simplistic) 4 MB sample file on my test VM took a little more than 1 second.

Comment: I tested on a shared drive. The slowness of the shared drive caused the performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Regex way.

After a little comments war with @dc7a9163d9 about possibilities that weren't part of the original deal, the following code does two things:

a) Replaces commas (,) with semicolons (;) inside CSV fields.

b) Replaces pairs of double quotes ("") with single quotes (') inside CSV fields.

```
$cRows = Get-Content -Path "file.csv"
$cNewRows = @()
foreach ($sRow in $cRows) {
    $sRow = $sRow `
        -replace '(?:(?<!^|,|[^"]"|"{3})),(?:(?!"[^"]|"{3}|$))', ';' `
        -replace '(?:(?<!^|[,]+))""', "'" -replace '""', "'"
    $cNewRows += $sRow
}

$cNewRows | Out-File -FilePath "test.txt"
```

Comment: However, the RE doesn't work when there is double quotes around the comma. `'123,"a"",""b,c",456' -replace '(?:(?<!")),(?:(?!"))', ';'`

Comment: Heh. Updated my answer.

Comment: How about if I want to replace `""` with `'`?

Comment: You just need to add one more `-replace` then. Updated answer.

Comment: `'123,"""a"",""b,c",456'  -replace '(?:(?<![^"]")),(?:(?!"[^"]))', ';' -replace '""', "'"` created a malformed CSV format `123;'"a';'b;c",456`.

Comment: Starts looking like fun. ) Updated. Anything else to look out for?

Comment: To test the double double quotes to single quotes, the test `'"""1,""2"",3""","a,""b"",c",456' -replace '(?:(?<!,))""(?:(?!,))', "'"` doesn't return the expected well-formed CSV format `"'1,'2',3'","a,'b',c",456`.

Comment: I thought you wanted to do ,->; replacement first. But here you go, now ""->' replace works on its own.